# Получение ответа с ajax запроса

Tags: php, ajax

Со страницы index.php обращаюсь к ajax.php. Необходимо взять значение переменной в ajax.php, отправить и вывести в index.php.
Итого, по замыслу должно вывести 100.
Написал такое - не работает.

index.php:

```
  <div id="money"></div>
  $.ajax({
  url: "ajax.php",
  success: function(html){
  $("#money").html(html);
  }
  });
  var write = getElementById("money");
  block.innerHTML(data);
```

ajax.php:

```
  <?php
  $a = 100;
  ?>
  <script>
  var data = <? echo $a; ?>;
  </script>
```

Comment: А если так? <php $a = 100; echo $a ?>

Answer (score 0):

Возвращайте **json строку** в php, и работайте с ней в js как с объектом в дальнейшем(т.е. лучше возвращайте не просто переменную а массив с ключем следующим образом).

index.php:

```
<div id="money"></div>
  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "ajax.php",
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(data){
     $("#money").html(data.a);
  }
});
```

ajax.php:

```
<?php
  $result['a'] = 100;
  echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: Не выводится 100.

Comment: @Holter запрос вообще отправляется, и что возвращает?

Answer (score 0):

index.php:

```
<div id="money"></div>
<script>
$.ajax({
        url: '/ajax.php',
        success: function(html){
            $("#money").html(html);
        }
    });
<script>
```

ajax.php:

```
<?php
$a = 100;
echo $a;
?>
```

У меня работает

Comment: Сорян, копирнул код из своего проекта и забыл удалить

Comment: Не выводится 100.